# Element-wise boolean operation between row of sparse matrix and list

Tags: python, list, numpy, boolean, or-operator

I want to carry out an element wise logical operation between a row of a sparse matrix and another list.

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
a=lil_matrix((3,3), dtype=bool)
b=[True,False,True]
a[2,:]=a[2,:] or b
```

However, this returns:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

There is already one very good explanation for why the error occurs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

However, `a.any()` or `a.all()` will return only one truth value and not perform something element wise. Also, `np.logical_or(a[2,:],b)` returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

Cast the list to `np.ndarray` and use `+` instead of `or`. For reasons I do not know the `bitwise_or` operator `|` (which one would use for arrays) does not work here.

```
a[2] += np.array(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectorized `or` is a `numpy` operation; there is no direct equivalent for a common list.  The most effective and readable way to do this is to convert your Boolean list to an np_array and *then* apply the operation, letting `numpy`'s processing to rule the process.